# Change text value dynamically in a spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I want to use a spinner in my app with a static list of choices, for example:

- Speed
- Altitude
- Latitude
- Longitude

So, when clicking on the spinner the drop down view appears and if I select altitude I want to display the altitude value and then update this value into the spinner itself (I've got a GPS service to get location data).

To achieve this I create my own adapter and override the `getView()` and the `getDropDownView()`:

```
package com.example.spinnertest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MySpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context _context;
    private ArrayList<String> _values;

    public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
        this._context = context;
        this._values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _values.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return _values.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layout = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layout.inflate(R.layout.item_spinner_value, null);
        }
        TextView valueTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_spinner_value_tv);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layout = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layout.inflate(R.layout.item_spinner_list, null);
        }
        ImageView imView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_spinner_list_iv);
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_spinner_list_tv);
        textView.setText(_values.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }   
}
```

In the `getView()` I can access the `TextView` where I want to display the dynamic value but I don't know how to access it from my `Activity`. Any idea how to do this?

My `MainActivity.java` :

```
package com.example.spinnertest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<String> maListe = new ArrayList<String>(){{add("Altitude");add("Speed");add("Longitude");add("Latitude");}};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spi = (MySpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        MySpinnerAdapter spiAd = new MySpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), maListe);
        spi.setAdapter(spiAd);
    }
}
```

I didn't implements my gps service yet. I'm just trying to solve my spinner problem.

Comment: can we see what you have in onCreate method of your activity and layout file please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change adapter in Spinner. OnItemSelected.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment! I try this and it works on a simple project but I get an other problem after this, so I decided to do it without spinner. see [http://stackoverflow.com/q/27015891](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27015891) for details.