# Why I can not launch my android application on an api10 emulator while minsdkversion is 10?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

Since I update my android sdk platforms tools to 21 and the android support library to 21.0.2, I've got a lot of trouble in some of my projects.
I succeed to resolved some of my issues but here I really don't know what is going on. So I have a project with :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

but if I want to use a virtual device with api level 10 the android device chooser says that the api 10 device is not compatible with my application.
If I change my targetSdkVersion to 20 or 19 the project is no more compatible with the appcompatv7:21 support library.
So I made some search to re-install an older version of the sdk and the support library but I didn't find how to this.

My configuration is :
Android SDK Tools 23.0.5
Android SDK Platform-tools 21
Android SDK Build-tools 21.1.1
Android Support Library 21.0.2
Google Play services 21

My android manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.package"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:versionCode="9"
    android:versionName="Version 1.02" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.my.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:name="com.my.package.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.package.LauncherActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.my.package.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.package.PreferencesActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_crab"
            android:theme="@style/PreferenceTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.package.ContactActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_crab"
            android:label="@string/contact"
            android:theme="@style/PreferenceTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.package.MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/map" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.package.AboutActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.my.package.ArticleService"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.my.package.BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.my.package.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="mykey" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I know it's not solving your problem, but that the moment when you should start using Gradle IMHO.

Comment: If you would've invested in your other questions, people would have liked to invest in you too. For example, in the following answer to your question you didn't give the user any feedback: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24753751/435605

Comment: Oh, and can you just zip the project and attach it? I think it would be much easier for others to answer your question. Also, can you first clean up your project to include just a single simple activity to make it easier?

Comment: For my previous question your right. I didn't take the time to do it, so I will post a comment on it. Sorry !

Comment: For my present question, I'm going to have a look to gradle like @shkschneider suggested it. Unfortunately it's a project for my company and I can't post sources like this. Maybe I can try to delete some code step by step and see when I can use an api 10 virtual device ?

Comment: I tried to close and open Eclipse many times but with no success. Finally I reboot my computer and now it works. Very strange. Anyway, I'll keep looking gradle. Thank for your help.